# What's the cause of this error, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm trying to create a search function, I'm following the code from https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-react-components/ Note that I'm using my own "API" and not the one freecodecamp uses. However I get an error that reads: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') What could be the cause of this

Here's my code, it's identical only difference is the fetch URL.

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
function Main() {
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
const data = Object.values(items);
const search_parameters = Object.keys(Object.assign({}, ...data));
// const search_parameters = ["title", ...data]
function search(data) {
    return items.filter(
      (item) =>
        search_parameters.some((parameter) =>//Error here
          item[parameter].toString().toLowerCase().includes(query)
        )
    );
  }
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:3005/movies')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])

  if (error) {
    return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
  } else if (!isLoaded) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <>
      <input
          type="search"
          name="search-form"
          id="search-form"
          className="search-input"
          placeholder="Search for..."
          onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
        />
        <div className='card-wrapper'>
        {search(data).map((item)=>(
            <div className="movie-card">
            <p className="title">{item.title}</p> <br></br>
            <img src={item.cover} className="card-img"/> <br></br>
        </div>
        ))}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }

 }

export default Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Propably there is problem in line:

```
item[parameter].toString().toLowerCase().includes(query)
```

There is no property named `parameter` (it should be named `property`) on your `item` object, therefore `undefined` has no `toString()` method. To fix this issue, you should check if such property exists first.

```
...
if (parameter in item) {
  return item[parameter].toString()
    .toLowerCase()
    .includes(query);
}
...
```